# HDMI Stop working after Macbook OS Update

Tags: mojave, hdmi

HDMI Stop working after Macbook OS Update to Mojave Version 10.14.3.  Was working perfectly. I tested cable and monitor and it works on other laptops.

Comment: Which Macbook are you using? What monitor are you connecting it to? Any other troubleshooting you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

So after some Google searches I found one fix that worked. Update the Display Link Driver located here:  https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/

Not sure what happened during the new Mojave Update to version 10.14.3 but after installing this new driver, my HDMI port to second monitor is now working.